# Play H.264 Encoded Stream in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, media, h.264, netcat

I have a Raspberry Pi getting video data from `raspivid` and piping that to `netcat`, which sends it to my PC where I can read each frame like this:

```
ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverChannel.socket().bind(new 
InetSocketAddress(Main.config.getInt("VIDEO_STREAM_PORT")));
serverChannel.configureBlocking(true);
SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();
InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = (InetSocketAddress) 
channel.getRemoteAddress();
int BUFFER_SIZE = 2 << 16 - 1;
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
while (channel.read(buff) != -1) {
   buff.flip();
   if (buff.hasRemaining()) {
      buff.compact();
   } else {
      buff.clear();
   }
}
```

What is the optimal way of playing these frames as video in JavaFX? Is there any way to do it besides decoding each frame as a BufferedImage and rendering that? Or is there another approach altogether that I'm missing?

On Linux you could do what I'm looking for just by using `netcat | mplayer` but I'd like to do this in a JavaFX app.

Comment: As I know Swing supports neither video nor sound capabilities. But JavaFX has a native support for this. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/overview.htm) tutorial. You can embed a JavaFX element into your Swing application using [JFXPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm).

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I actually am using JavaFX, but it's late at night and somehow I got the two confused. My apologies.

Comment: JavaFX has media support in the [`javafx.scene.media`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) package. The Javadoc of the package indicates that H.264 encoding is supported. You'll want to use a [`Media`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html). Unfortunately, `Media` doesn't support arbitrary input. It takes a `String` of a URI that points to the media source and creates its own connection (based on protocol). If you're tied to using a `SocketChannel` then I'm not sure how you'd _stream_ it (if it's even possible).